# Sharing rules not respected for related queries

Tags: rest, sharing, sharing-rule

I have set my `Account` to `Private`.
I have `Activity` (`Task`) set to `Private`

I have two users - `Joe Schmoe` and `Karen Hoyts`.

I have created an account `Joe's Account`.
Under that account, i create a task `Karen's task` and assign it to `Karen Hoyts`.

Using the UI, `Karen` can see the account name on that task, but when she clicks on it, she gets

> Looks like there's a problem.
>   Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID shown here and any other related details. The requested resource does not exist

(that is **good** and expected).

Now, using the REST API (the standard REST API, `/services/data/v48.0/query`), i run the query as `Karen`

```
SELECT Id, Account.Name, Account.My_Custom_Field__c FROM Task WHERE Id = '<<task id here>>'
```

And **boom** -> Karen just pulled out data from Account that she does not have sharing to.

Why is that?

Comment: Are you using standard rest api or from apex ?

Comment: Standard REST API

Comment: How are you running the API as Karen

Comment: @identigral There is a connected app in the org, `Karen` authorised that and i get an access token. I can use her access token to issue queries to REST API.

Comment: I do not see this behavior actually. It prints null for other fields.I think something is wrong in your testing

Comment: I used workbench to test this.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava so you used workbench logging in as that second user who is not an admin?

Comment: Also, could it be the bug in rest api only? Iirc workbench uses metadata tooling which is a different api

Comment: @zaitsman I tested using rest utility of the workbench!

Comment: The issue might have something to do with the way connected app is authorized or it might be a genuine new bug not related to connected app..or both!

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with [Access Grants](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_record_access_under_the_hood.meta/salesforce_record_access_under_the_hood/uth_grants.htm), specifically Implicit Grants.

> Grants that occur when non-configurable record-sharing behaviors built
>   into Salesforce Sales, Service, and Portal applications grant access
>   to certain parent and child records. For example, with this default
>   logic, sometimes referred to as built-in sharing, users can view a
>   parent account record if they have access to its child opportunity,
>   case, or contact record. If those users have access to a parent
>   account record, they can also access its child opportunity, case, and
>   contact records.

Comment: If that were the case, would i not be able to access this record via UI also?

Comment: As Karen, you can see the account name on the task record. This tells me you can see any account related data on the task, which is what your query is doing. Try querying for the account record as Karen. You shouldn't be able to query it.

Comment: Correct, i can not query the record directly, but i can download ALL the fields using navigational properties (Account.X).